# Execute a Kettle transformation

Tags: java, cmd, execute, kettle

What is the minimal software necessary to execute a **Kettle transformation** from a .ktr file? It is necessary to install the Kettle software to run the transformation from the command line?

A good option is to create a Java App to run it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you will need: java installed, dowload the pentaho data-integration pack: into this pack you will find-

-**spoon.sh** (aka Kettle), the visual tool to design and develop your jobs and transformations,

-**pan.sh**:  the command line program to execute **transformations**.

-**kitchen.sh** : the command line program to execute **jobs**.

-**carte.sh**: a web server that you could send your transformations or jobs via **http**.

Comment: Thanks, but I was asking how to run the .ktr file without downloading the PDI. I already ran it by developing a java app.